# What research (if any) is being done with regard to a hidden variable theory of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, bohmian-mechanics

From Bell’s theorem and the Kochen-Specker theorem we know that any hidden variable model hoping to reproduce the predictions of quantum mechanics must be both non-local and contextual. What model satisfy these conditions and what research is being done?

Comment: I deleted the second question. Try to ask exactly one question per post.

Comment: Fair enough I shall  that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden variables theories is not the direction modern research actually goes since they are considered a mere complication of the systems without leading to further developing of the current one. The most popular non-local (deterministic) hidden variable theory is the [De Broglie-Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) which is considered to be equivalent to the other quantum mechanics formalities in terms of prediction even if this is disputed.